# How to hyperlink each element of an array, if the array is generated from a database?

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, hyperlink

In my website, users have the ability to create pools (groups). Obviously, when they create a pool, the pool information (pool name, etc) is sent to my database. Then in the user's profile, I retrieve all the pools that they are in from the database and display them on the page.

However, at the moment, these are displayed as just text. I want them to be hyperlinked to a separate page that is the pool's profile. Can anyone help me do this? My code is as follows.

```
<?php
    session_start();


    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","UltimateLeague");

    $query = ("SELECT * FROM userpool WHERE userid=".$_SESSION['user_id']."");
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query); //Finding the pools that the current user is in

    $poolid = array(); //Creating an array of these pools

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $pool_id[] = $row['pool_id'];

    }


    $ids = join(',',$pool_id); //Finding the names of these pools in a separate table
    $query2 = "SELECT * FROM pools WHERE pool_id IN ($ids)";
    $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $query2);

    $pool_name = array(); //Creating an array of these names
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result2) > 0) {
        while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
        $pool_name[] = $row2['pool_name'];
    }

    }

?>
```

Then, the displaying of the pools:

```
<html>

<p><h5>Below is a list of pools that you are currently in.</h5></p>
  <ul>
     <?php foreach( $pool_name as $pool): ?>
         <ul>
         <?= $pool ?>
         </ul>
     <?php endforeach; ?>
  </ul>

</html>
```

So in this loop, how can I link each of the $pools to a separate page?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should use a `JOIN` instead of two separate queries.

Comment: I'm quite new to this, so I didn't even know you could do that. Thank you. However, it doesn't quite solve my hyperlinking problem.

Comment: I never said it would, it's just a recommendation of how to use databases properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the pool ID in the URL of a link.

```
<ul>
<?php while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2): ?>
    <li>
    <a href="show_pool.php?id=<?= $row2['pool_id'] ?>"><?= $row2['pool_name'] ?></a>
    </li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
```

You should combine your two queries into a single JOIN:

```
SELECT p.pool_id, p.pool_name
FROM userpool AS u
JOIN pools AS p ON u.pool_id = p.pool_id
WHERE u.userid = {$_SESSION['user_id']}
```